# Is there a way to silently abort creating a model in Laravel?

Tags: laravel

I have a ProductTags model that is in a one to many relationships to my product. I need to prevent the same model id and tag from being duplicated in multiple records. In the migration I have `$table->unique(['product_uuid', 'tag']);` but that means if I attempt to create a model that is a duplicate of an existing model I get an integrity constraint violation.

So when a ProductTags model is created, before it gets saved it needs to check the database for an existing version then abort its own creation. I would prefer to do this in the model so I only have to implement it once instead of both the controllers and factory.

I tried to override the create method to intercept it, but when I seeded, it doesn't seem to be called at all.

```php
class ProductTag extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'product_uuid', 'tag',
    ];

    public function create($data){
        if(
            ProductTag::where('product_uuid', '=', $data['product_uuid'])->
            where('tag','=', $data['tag'])
        ){
            return false;
        }
        return parent::create($data);
    }
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by "if I attempt to create a model that is a duplicate of an existing model"? are you talking about models or entries in your db?

Comment: You can use Model Events if I understood your question. Take a look here : https://laravel-news.com/laravel-model-events-getting-started

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `->exists()` function on the query builder to check if a record exists for that query:

```
public function create($data){
    $productTag = self::where('product_uuid', $data['product_uuid'])
        ->where('tag', $data['tag']);

    if ($productTag->exists()) {
        return false;
    }

    return self::create($data);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What about using [firstOrCreate](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#other-creation-methods)

```
public function create($data)
{
    return self::firstOrCreate( // self or use ProductTag
        [
            'product_uuid' => $data['product_uuid'],
            'tag' => $data['tag']
        ],
        $data
    );
}
```

I am just not sure if you can invoke it on `self`, but you can do it on the model for sure.

This will return an instance of `ProductTag` back in any case so you can chain other methods

Comment: I thought of this, however if `false` is needed as a return then it would not work as it would always return a record even if it did not create a new one.

Comment: @thisiskelvin he has options to chose now :) I am just providing an answer based on what I understood. So your answer is good as well :)

Comment: Definitely! Good he has a few